# displaying and sorting comments by a custom field (using PODS plugin)

Tags: custom-field, comments, pods-framework

In my blog, i answer comments inline by editing them to add "admin says: blah blah". i do this so i won't bump up the comment count with all my admin comments.

I am using the PODS plugin to add a custom field to all of my comments, and when i edit comments to include my answer, i mark the current time. i use this to store the date/time i modified the comment - the field is called "answered".

is there any way i could add a code snippet to my sidebar which would display the latest comments i've replied to? (which means, edited to add my answer at the bottom). i know that there's a widget that displays just the latest comments by the publish date, but i'd like to display comments by the edit date, using my newly created PODS custom field ("answered"). this would work, for example, even if i just replied to a bunch of comments from 3 years ago.

I tried asking this twice on the PODS 2.x support forum but no answer... thanks!

Comment: Sorry but [questions about third party plugins are off-topic here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Anyway, you can get comments sorted by custom fields using [`WP_Comment_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query) class or [`get_comments()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments). Give it a try.